# Android parse value from .sqlite file

Tags: android, sqlite, data-retrieval

How to parse value from .sqlite file, i n my sqlite file there are more than 1000 records now i need to retrieve all the values and need to show that in a listview, i have saved that file in to my asset folder, is there any way to do as like parsing csv file

All the suggestions are most welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had database which has more than 1000 of records and it's in assets folder of application...

For that you need to copy asset database to installed app folder and then use it using SQLiteOpenHelper..

For more details with example you can take reference from here..

[Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

- Save your data into SQLite, create `ContentProvider` to allow querying/updating data
  See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
- Use `CursorLoader` and `CursorAdapter` to load data from `ContentProvider` and bind them to your list view asynchronously
  See: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

The whole process seems to be overwhelmed at first with a lot of things need to be created, but once done you will get the flow.